# Scope PC software to interface with a real scope

Tags: oscilloscope, pc

I have a HP54645D mixed-signal oscilloscope that can be fully controlled via RS-232. Is there some general-purpose oscilloscope software that provides a scope-like interface, kind of like the interface of Rigol's 7000 series scopes, that can be hooked up to any scope?

I would have no problem writing my own driver for it, but I know I won't be able to write the full software myself.

I am in the process of writing a python wrapper for the RS-232 interface, but in that case, I would also have to write an actual GUI application as well.

What I'm looking for is something like Sigrok PulseView (which would be a perfect fit, but it's combining both of my arch-nemesi: raw C and "self-documenting" code).

Not sure if this is technically the right place to ask this question but it looked like the best fit and I figured if someone knew I'd find them here.

Comment: I've been looking for a generic oscilloscope & logic analyser front-end that can be adapted to work with my custom data-acquisition hardware, and have failed to find anything suitable. The closest seems to be Sigrok PulseView, which can work with mixed-signal scopes, but it doesn't support your scope, and writing a custom device driver is a non-trivial exercise - the interface is quite complex, with a tendency to lock up if there are any communication problems.

Comment: Is the [software provided by Keysight](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/support/54645D/100mhz-200msas-mixed-signal-oscilloscope.html#drivers) of any use?

Comment: @rdtsc No, unfortunately not. While it may be supported by the IO libraries, it's not supported by their BenchVue or Command Expert software, which is not much of a surprise given that it was made around 1995, and that the highest baudrate it can transmit at is 19200 baud, which makes a realtime display pretty hard to pull off. In addition to that, this scope is from the era where Agilent was just formed (it's still got a HP badge, but an Agilent service sticker).
And those IO libraries require Windows, while I use Linux, so I'm just writing my own library in python.

Comment: @jayben Yeah, PulseView looks pretty much like what I've been looking for. But, since there isn't a driver, I would have to scrap my current python driver and face my nemesis, raw C. And all the source code I looked at is also the famous self-explanatory code that doesn't need docstrings.

Comment: Excellent; best wishes.  Please consider Github or similar.  Who knows, might find a few other people willing to dust off their old 'scope and help.  (I bet Mr. Carlson has one.)

Comment: Well, luckily I do have found HPs original documentation for the scope (a windows help file, but that was nothing a little converting couldn't fix), and now I'm grinding towards an interface library that works with my scope and at least provides a modern wrapper for serial commands like `:TIM:MOD XY` (setting the scope to XY mode), and adding some inline docstrings so that you don't have to bust out the helpfile every time. And yes, I do fully plan on putting that on GitHub at some point.

Comment: Nevermind. I know myself too well to put that off into the future because I would just forget. First version is pushed to github, can be found here: https://github.com/vguttmann/libscopehp/

Comment: look at page 2-7 at https://cal.equipment/doc/HP_Agilent_Keysight/HP%2054645A,%2054645D%20Programmer.pdf

Comment: @jsotola I'm using a help file that came alongside such a file (they're still up on the keysight product page, as the HP measurement division got split off into Agilent, which was subsequently acquired by keysight). I am in the process of writing a python wrapper for the RS-232 interface, but that's definitely not a finished application I can use to communicate with the scope and display a waveform, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Vincent, you might try Matplotlib in Python, it it pretty easy to draw line graphs with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for my scope there seems to be no such software. For some scopes, Sigrok PulseView seems to be a good fit, but if you don't like C, or "self-documenting code", don't think of writing your own PulseView driver.

For my scope, I'm writing a python wrapper for the RS-232 interface, which can be found here: https://github.com/vguttmann/libscopehp/.